# $attribute->newInstance() failing with Symfony bundle attributes

Tags: symfony

When my attribute class is local, I'm able to call ->newInstance(), but not when it's in a bundle.

```php
// MyBundle.php
        $builder->autowire(Workflow::class)
            ->setPublic(true);
```

And the application that's calling it:

```php
        $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($entityClass);
        foreach ($reflectionClass->getAttributes(Workflow::class) as $attribute) {

            dump($attribute->getArguments()); // arguments are there.
            dd($attribute->newInstance()); 
        }
```

Fails with Attribute class not found, but works fine if the Attribute is in App\Attribute.

Almost certainly this is a Dependency Injection issue, but I can't tell how to make the attributes public.